# How to get a list of all ansible that support a given platform, e.g. Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I am considering migrating from Puppet into Ansible.

From my perspective, one of the strengths of the Ansible is the relative ease of writing modules (It so happens that I don't know Ruby, but I know Python). But before I start writing my own, I'd like to see what is available at the moment.

If I want to use ansible efficiently, one of the first things to do is to see what tasks are covered by the already existing modules.

I understand that most of the modules are compatible with Red Hat Linux and if I plan using it under Ubuntu I need to have a means to filter out those, that don't support it at the moment.

I can't find any "comaptibility" tag with modules listed on [modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_all_modules.html).

Does it mean, that I need to open each module individually and check the description to see if the author mentioned my platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of Ansible modules will work on all the major linux platforms (and potentially lesser distros as well) in large part because they're based on python and python modules, which are highly platform independent across linux distributions.  Where there are platform-dependent differences you'll find that most, if not all of the core modules will support not only the major linux platforms but other platforms like FreeBSD, Solaris, etc. as well.

Take a look at the [source for the user module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/system/user.py), for example.  It imports the `platform` python module, which attempts to retrieve as much platform-specific information as possible.  It helps python programs to be as platform independent as possible.  If you take a closer look at the user module you'll also see that it has specific cases for different operating systems like various versions of BSD, Solaris, and even AIX.

Unfortunately there isn't much official documentation on platform support as you've discovered.  Aside from comments in the module documentation and in the module source code there isn't much else.  However, having said that, I think it's a pretty safe bet that all the core modules, and most if not all of the additional modules, will work fine on Ubuntu. After all, their commercial product, Ansible Tower, is [supported on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/installandreference/prerequisites_refguide.html#configuration-and-installation-for-ansible-with-ubuntu). They wouldn't do that if Ansible itself didn't work properly on those platforms.